# Traefik forward SSL to php-nginx docker image (https traffic to Laravel)

Tags: docker, nginx, https, traefik

I need some expert advice on Traefik or Nginx setup. Some clue will be good.

starapp - I want to run a Laravel App here. I notice when a request reaches laravel app using HTTP, the response becomes mixed. So I am trying to send the entire SSL traffic to laravel app.

Here is my docker-compose for php-nginx docker. I can start the docker. however when a request hit this instance. I get error in docker logs of starapp.

docker-compose.yml

```
starapp:
image: webdevops/php-nginx:7.4         
container_name: starapp
depends_on:
  - mysql    
restart: always
environment:
  - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
  - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
  - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
  - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
  - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=256M
  - WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=app.starthardware.com.my
volumes:
  - ./starhardware.com.my/app/:/app
  #- ./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  #- ./etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
  - /opt/containers/ngixbased/data/assets/ssl/app.starhardware.com.my:/etc/ssl            

expose:
  - 443
        
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.http.services.starapp.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https      
  - traefik.http.routers.starapp-secure.rule=Host(`app.starhardware.com.my`)      
  - traefik.http.routers.starapp-secure.entrypoints=https     
  - traefik.http.routers.starapp-secure.tls=true
  - traefik.http.routers.starapp-secure.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt
 
networks:
  - proxy      
  - backend
```

When a request hit this docker instance I get the below error

```
starapp       | [18-Aug-2021 04:12:22] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 49
starapp       | [18-Aug-2021 04:12:22] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
starapp       | 2021-08-18 04:12:23,352 INFO success: syslogd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
starapp       | [SYSLOG] CRON[86]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
starapp       | 192.168.144.3 - - [18/Aug/2021:04:22:29 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xFC\x03\x034\xF1\xAF|Z\xEE\xC2\xD9rU\x07\x99:\xF8^a\xB6\xC1\x91\x18\x80\xF4\xAE\xE7!A\xC9\xF8" 400 173 "-" "-"
starapp       | 192.168.144.3 - - [18/Aug/2021:04:22:29 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xFC\x03\x03\x03q\x1B\xC3\x18_\xE1" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

Next I did a to see the nginx -T status within the docker instance.

```
root@cdeb5cd6f9e8:/# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /docker.stdout ;
        error_log /docker.stderr ;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/10-docker.conf:
include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/global.conf;
include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/php.conf;
include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.conf;

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/global.conf:
# deprecated

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/php.conf:
# deprecated

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/10-php.conf:
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.conf:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name  _ app.starthardware.com.my docker;

    root "/app";
    index index.php;

    include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/*.conf;
}

##############
# SSL
##############

server {
    listen 443 default_server;

    server_name  _ app.starthardware.com.my docker;

    root "/app";
    index index.php;

    include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/*.conf;
    include /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.ssl.conf;
}

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-general.conf:
client_max_body_size 50m;

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf:
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-log.conf:
access_log   /docker.stdout;
error_log    /docker.stderr warn;

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-php.conf:
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.ssl.conf:
ssl           on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # not possible to do exclusive
ssl_ciphers   'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_certificate     /opt/docker/etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /opt/docker/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

root@cdeb5cd6f9e8:/# code here
```

Any suggestion ? or what else I can check to identify the source of this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: We did simiar thing for our private docker registry. We placed nginx in-front of docker registry. Hence only https traffic is accepted by dr

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I am missing something in nginx

Answer (score 0):

This is our `docker-compose` file.

```
nginx:
  
  image: "nginx:alpine"
  ports:
    - 5000:443
  links:
    - registry:registry
  volumes:
    - ./auth:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./auth/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

registry:

  image: registry:2.7.0
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/registry
```

We use `nginx` front. Here `registry` part related to actually docker-registry container. I think you can replace your app there. But using `webdevops/php-nginx:7.4` may give you problems as it has inbuild `nginx`